# Tricking Java Web Start About the Operating System

Tags: java, macos

I'm restoring an antique vehicle and for that I use the EPC (Electronic Parts Catalog) from Mercedes Benz.  (Membership is free, so those wanting to see the program I'm talking about can go [here](https://epc.startekinfo.com/epc/login.jsp) if they want to check it out.)  To get to the program, there's a sign in page, then another page with a link.  Clicking the link downloads a file called ewa-net.jnlp and it's launched with JavaWS.

I used to use this program on my Linux system and it worked.  I remember I changed either the osname variable in my /etc directory or I changed the OS in Firefox before I ran the program and changed it back when I was done, so it wouldn't effect any other Java program.  The EPC program worked just fine under those conditions.  I strongly suspect the reason for requiring Windows is more of a defensive move (for example, to avoid liability or to avoid having to fix bugs on multiple OSes).

I'm aware that making changes like this can mess up a program, but this is used only to go through the parts catalog and to examine part diagrams, which helps in determining part locations or placements or helps the parts guys because I can help them find the page a part is on quickly if I've done my research before calling them.  I'm not saving data or modifying anything on a disk drive or elsewhere (although I do sometimes take a screenshot and print it out).

I cannot download ewa-net.jnlp and just run it whenever I want. I have to go through the HTML login page, then run the program from their site, so I can't just run the program from the command line or something like that.  (Unless that replaces running it with JavaWS right after I log in.)

Now I'm using an iMac, using Snow Leopard.  I tried finding and changing the osname on here, and it didn't work.

Right now whenever I need to use the EPC, I have to start up a Windows VM in Parallels and about the only reason I use that Windows VM is for this program.

Is there some way I can trick Java so when I run this program, it thinks it's on Windows?  I'm aware this could crash, but since the catalog worked fine on Linux, I want to at least try it on OS X.

I thought maybe I could use a wrapper script that runs JavaWS, but I'm not quite sure what to do and, as I said previously, changing the osname setting didn't seem to work.

Is there anything that might help me trick this program into thinking it's on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what is applying the Windows restriction.

It is possible for a JNLP file to specify elements for specific operating systems only, thus effectively restricting it to a particular OS. So if the JNLP file contains something like this...

```
<resources os="Windows XP">
    <j2se version="1.5+" />
    <jar href="/example.jar" />
</resources>
```

...then that could be what's preventing you from running it on Mac OS X. Have a look at the JNLP file (I'm unable to see it, as a non-US resident I can't sign up myself) and see if that's the cause. If it is maybe you can edit it. Why is it that you said you can't download ewa-net.jnlp? If you can download the JNLP file, edit it to have `os="Mac OS X"`, then double-click it to run it (or right-click and choose `Open With` > `Java Web Start`).

Alternately, the reason why changing osname didn't work for you *could* be that you changed it in the wrong installation of Java. Apple moved the installation location of Java sometime (I think) after Snow Leopard was released. So you may find your installation in either of these locations:

- /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
- /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

If you only updated one of these locations, you may have to do it in the other location too.

Comment: I guess I could download it.  The issue is that I can't just run ewa-net.jnlp alone.  I have to sign in and start a session through the .jsp pages, then once I'm logged in, I can start an EPC session when the file is downloaded.  I haven't programmed in Java in years, so I can't remember how this is done, but my guess would be that a session ID might be passed along with the file, but I don't remember if that can be done.  I may also be able to sign in, THEN start the file on my computer - it didn't occur to me before to try that.

Comment: Okay, looked at the file itself.  (I'm mixing things up, I did applets, but don't remember using .jnlp files - like I said, it's been years.)  It does have a jsessionid in it, with my username, so it creates a custom file for each login.  It's late, so I'll try updating both locations tomorrow.  If that works, then I'll write a script, or maybe a wrapper script for use with the browser that'll let me pick the OS on launch.

Comment: Well, I tried looking through the directories and using grep to find any place the OS was specified.  I know on Linux, under Java 1.2 (yes, I've been 'out' a good while), some of the properties were in a text file in /etc.  But I couldn't find a single text file that specified what OS this system has, so this didn't work.  To trick Java, I'd have to be able to find where that info was stored (and hope it's easily edited).